# Uncaught syntax error in dynamic jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I've been working on a piece of dynamic JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * from pm_schedule";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    foreach ($result as $row) 
        {
        echo 
            "$('#updatebtn".$row['id']."').click(function() {
             $('#result".$row['id']."').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow')
        $.post('process.php', $('#updateform".$row['id']."').serialize(), 
            });";
        }
?>
});
```

It expands to the following when I run it on my server:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#updatebtn1').click(function () {
        $('#result1').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow')
        $.post('process.php', $('#updateform1').serialize(),
        });

    $('#updatebtn2').click(function () {
        $('#result2').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow')
        $.post('process.php', $('#updateform2').serialize(),
        });

    $('#updatebtn3').click(function () {
        $('#result3').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow')
        $.post('process.php', $('#updateform3').serialize(),
        });

    $('#updatebtn4').click(function () {
        $('#result4').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow')
        $.post('process.php', $('#updateform4').serialize(),
        });

    $('#updatebtn5').click(function () {
        $('#result5').show('slow').delay(4000).hide('slow')
        $.post('process.php', $('#updateform5').serialize(),
        });
    });
```

Google Chrome keeps returning an uncaught syntax error for the code above - any idea as to why? Please note that I have to make edits to the first code block and not the second.

Comment: I'd say it's the comma after each `serialize()` and the missing `)`

Comment: why all the code duplication? Could consolidate to one `click` handler by using class rather than ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the comma `,` at the end here `$('#updateform".$row['id']."').serialize(),`<-- with a `)`

Answer (score 0):

there is a missing semicolon  after `hide('slow')` and additional comma after `serialize()`